# The conversion of a hex value of length 16 isn't correct

Tags: python-3.x

I have a hex value of 16 digits (i.e., length 16) that I want to convert to binary as the following:

```
n = '5851F42D00000000'    # length = 16
bin_ = bin(int(n, 16))[2:]
print(len(bin_))
```

I get here 63 but I expect the length of the resulted binary to be 64. Am I doing something wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bin` doesn't give you leading zeroes, because it has no way of knowing how many leading zeroes you would want. You can get the desired behaviour using string formatting:

```py
>>> n = '5851F42D00000000'
>>> '{:064b}'.format(int(n, 16))
'0101100001010001111101000010110100000000000000000000000000000000'
>>> len(_)
64
```

The format string `{:064b}` formats an integer in binary, with leading zeroes up to length 64.

Answer (score 0):

This number in binary has a leading zero:

```
>>> f'{int(n, 16):064b}'
'0101100001010001111101000010110100000000000000000000000000000000'
```

`bin` will return the shortest possible representation, not including leading zeros:

```
>>> bin(int(n, 16))
'0b101100001010001111101000010110100000000000000000000000000000000'
   ^ there's technically a zero before that
```